# unmerge arbitrary merge in cvs/svn

Tags: svn, version-control, cvs

In CVS and/or SVN is there a way of unmerging an arbitrary merge (as in, not necessarily the last merge)

Let's say tere are 4 branches: trunk, feature1, feature2, feature3.

All feature* branches are merged into trunk one by one. Is there any way of cleanly 'unmerging' any of the feature branches?

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Subversion you can use a so called reverse merge.

```
svn merge -c -MergedRev URL/trunk
```

The "-MergedRev" defines the revision where you merged the branch into the trunk which is usually exact a single revision.

```
svn merge -c -24567 URL/trunk
```

In CVS this can be done using instructions at http://dev.usw.at/manual/cvs/cvs-general/cvstrain-6.7.4.html. Since CVS has independent revisions for each file, the reverse merge would need to be performed for every affected file

Comment: Reverse merge is the word! Thanks! I suppose svn benefits here from single revision number. I found some stuff on reverse merging in CVS but that would need to be done on every single file merged.